# Identifying slow queries for Postgresql on RDS

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, amazon-rds

I have enabled the logging for Postgres queries which are taking longer than 5000 ms.
But in logs, there are lot of queries that are taking less time than the specified time when I ran those queries for the same DB using pgAdmin.

Related parameter set in parameter group:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 5000ms
log_statement = all
```

Are all the queries being logged? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `log_statement` to not log all queries

```
log_statement = none
```

and instead, enable logging slow queries

```
log_min_duration_statement = 5000ms
```

these two settings **are not related to each other**.

Consult [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-logging.html) for more details about configurations.